# Problema com paginação wordpress (retorna 404)

Tags: wordpress

Estou fazendo o index de um site e nele eu faço uma pesquisa dos posts, alias várias pesquisas, e a ultima delas tem paginação que é os últimos posts cadastrados.

*Estou fazendo a consulta do seguinte modo:*

```
<?php query_posts(array('posts_per_page' => 2, 'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1), 'meta_query' => array(array('key' => 'destaque', 'value' => 'on', 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS')))); ?>
```

Ai depois do while eu coloco:

```
<?php echo paginate_links(); ?>
```

ele mostra os dois posts da pagina e os links da paginação, mas ele vai pra 404. O que pode ser?

Comment: existe um Stack Exchange só para wordpress ! http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Se você faz várias consultas, não se esqueça de zerar a query do WP, desta maneira:

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

De acordo com a [documentação](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query) do WP, este método deve ser chamado sempre que você invoca o `query_posts()`.

Caso você esteja trabalhando com Custom Posts, recomendo também que faça um flush nas suas regras de permalinks (basta alterar para algum outro e depois voltar para o que estava). Em vezes, o 404 pode ocorrer por algum conflito nessas regras.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que através do próprio painel de administração do Wordpress você pode corrigir este problema.

Primeiro vá em Configurações > Leitura, e altere o valor do campo "As páginas do blog mostram no máximo" para 2, em seguida salve as alterações.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois vá em Configurações > Links Permanentes, nesta página somente clique em Salvar Alterações para que o Wordpress "refaça" toda a estrutura de links.